# Can I install membrane and new tile over existing tile?

Tags: tile

I removed the tile from the hallway a few years ago and installed hardwood flooring. The tile kept breaking into small pieces and scarred up the walls. I had a heck of a time removing all the thinset in order to get the cement subfloor flat / smooth. I am trying to avoid that in the laundry room. I am laying porcelain tile and prefer not to remove old tile. I have tiled over many other ceramic surfaces without a problem, but there are small cracks here and know that membrane works on concrete, so thought, why not over old tile and then install new tile over that?

Can I install an anti-fracture membrane over old tile that is structurally sound and then install new tile over the membrane? I am trying to not remove the old tile even though it has some minor cracks.

Comment: "*I am trying to not remove the old tile even though it has some minor cracks.*"  Why?  Is there a *good* reason you do not want to remove the old tile and install new tile  the correct way? How will the new floor height affect doors and transitions?

Comment: What kind of tile? You may not get mortar to bond well with glossy glazed surfaces.